# Duplicate resources com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml in Android during build process after adding Crashlytics

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase, crashlytics-android

I have added latest version of `react-native-firebase` `crashlytics` 8.1.1 and I'm getting an error in Android during the build:

> Duplicate resources in com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml

Any ideas how is possible to fix this issue? This file was automatically generated by Crashlytics.

[image]

P.S: if delete `com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml` it would be possible to make app build. However, I'm not sure how important that file is. Will Crashlytics work correctly if there wouldn't be this file in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml` and after that everything worked as expected!